# For loop with file names in R

Tags: r, loops, filenames

I have a list of files like:

`nE_pT_sbj01_e2_2.csv`,
`nE_pT_sbj02_e2_2.csv`,
`nE_pT_sbj04_e2_2.csv`,
`nE_pT_sbj05_e2_2.csv`,
`nE_pT_sbj09_e2_2.csv`,
`nE_pT_sbj10_e2_2.csv`

As you can see, the name of the files is the same with the exception of 'sbj' (the number of the subject) which is not consecutive.

I need to run a for loop, but I would like to retain the original number of the subject. How to do this?
I assume I need to replace `length(file)` with something that keeps the original number of the subject, but not sure how to do it.

```
setwd("/path")

file = list.files(pattern="\\.csv$") 
for(i in 1:length(file)){
  data=read.table(file[i],header=TRUE,sep=",",row.names=NULL)
  source("functionE.R")
  Output = paste("e_sbj", i, "_e2.Rdata")
  save.image(Output)
}
```

The code above gives me as output:

`e_sbj1_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj2_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj3_e2.Rdata`,
`e_sbj4_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj5_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj6_e2.Rdata`.

Instead, I would like to obtain:

`e_sbj01_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj02_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj04_e2.Rdata`,
`e_sbj05_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj09_e2.Rdata`,`e_sbj10_e2.Rdata`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the extension "csv", then add "Rdata", and use filenames in the loop, for example:

```
myFiles <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$") 

for(i in myFiles){
  myDf <- read.csv(i)
  outputFile <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(i), ".Rdata")
  outputFile <- gsub("nE_pT_", "e_", outputFile, fixed = TRUE)
  save(myDf, file = outputFile)
}
```

---

**Note:** I changed your variable names, try to avoid using function names as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

If you use regular expressions and `sprintf` (or `paste0`), you can do it easily without a loop:

```
fls <- c('nE_pT_sbj01_e2_2.csv', 'nE_pT_sbj02_e2_2.csv', 'nE_pT_sbj04_e2_2.csv', 'nE_pT_sbj05_e2_2.csv', 'nE_pT_sbj09_e2_2.csv', 'nE_pT_sbj10_e2_2.csv')


sprintf('e_%s_e2.Rdata',regmatches(fls,regexpr('sbj\\d{2}',fls)))

[1] "e_sbj01_e2.Rdata" "e_sbj02_e2.Rdata" "e_sbj04_e2.Rdata" "e_sbj05_e2.Rdata" "e_sbj09_e2.Rdata" "e_sbj10_e2.Rdata"
```

---

You can easily feed the vector to a function (if possible) or feed the function to the vector with `sapply` or `lapply`

```
fls_new <- sprintf('e_%s_e2.Rdata',regmatches(fls,regexpr('sbj\\d{2}',fls)))

res <- lapply(fls_new,function(x) yourfunction(x))
```

Comment: It's because I need to use a function inside the loop. Would that work even with a function? `source("functionE.R")`

Comment: depends on your function .. if it's not taking a vector input, you can just do a simple function loop or preferable use `sapply` or `lapply`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you only change extension from .csv to .Rdata, remove last "_2" and change prefix from "nE_pT" to "e". If yes, this should work:

```
Output = sub("_2.csv", ".Rdata", sub("nE_pT, "e", file[i]))
```